# Bug in PTX ISA (carry propagation)?

Tags: cuda, ptx

Is there a bug in Cuda? I have run the following code on my GTX580 and r1 is zero at the end. I expect that it is one due to carry propagation? I have tested the code with Cuda Toolkit 4.2.9 and 5.5 and use "nvcc -arch=sm_20 bug.cu -o bug  && ./bug" to compile and run it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>

__global__ void bug()
{
  unsigned int r1 = 0;
  unsigned int r2 = 0;

  asm( "\n\t"
       "sub.cc.u32 %0, 0, 1;\n\t"
       "addc.cc.u32 %1, 0, 0;\n\t"
     : "=r"(r1), "=r"(r2) );

  printf("r1 >> %04X\n", r1);
  printf("r2 >> %04X\n", r2);

}

int main(void)
{
  float *a_d;
  cudaMalloc((void **) &a_d, 1);

  bug <<< 1,1 >>> ();

  cudaFree(a_d);
}

Output
r1 >> FFFFFFFF
r2 >> 0000
```

Comment: Are you using windows or linux?  When I compile and run your code, I get the opposite result, i.e. `r1 >> FFFFFFFF` and `r2 >> 0000`  It might be better if you provide a complete, compilable code, along with the compile command you are using to build it.

Comment: Oh, damn it, you are right. I have corrected my code. But also on your machine r2 = 0 instead of r2 = 1? Very strange. How is it possible? I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: @Crovella: I have created a small sample program. I use "nvcc -arch=sm_20 bug.cu -o bug  && ./bug" to compile and run it.

Comment: Is there a reason you would want to run this particular sequence?  The carry instructions are mainly intended for extended precision integer arithmetic, i.e. sequences of adds or sequences of subtracts or sequences of multiplys.  If I convert your code to a sequence of subtracts (e.g. convert the addc instruction to `subc.u32 %1, 1, 0;`, I get the expected result (0 for r2).  Is there any particular purpose to the code you have shown?

Comment: @Crovella: This is part of a much more complex algorithm where I use extended precision integer arithmetic. With the last command (addc) I want to check if an overflow occurs.

Comment: You should probably check using an instruction that matches the last carry-arithmetic instruction you issued.  So if the last instruction was a subtract, use a subtract to check for borrow.  If the last instruction was an add, use an add to check for carry.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're making some assumptions about the `CC.CF` flag referenced in the [PTX ISA documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#extended-precision-integer-arithmetic-instructions) that may not be valid.

Note that the definition of specific states (e.g. 0 or 1) of this bit are never given that I can see.  Furthermore, I don't find any mapping between the definition of "carry-in/carry-out" and "borrow-in/borrow-out"

Stated another way, I think you are assuming that a "borrow" status in this flag is identical to a "carry" status.  In other words, you are assuming something like:

```
CF:  
0    =  (NO CARRY) or (NO BORROW)
1    =  (CARRY) or (BORROW)
```

But such a truth table or mapping is never given.  Furthermore the manual states:

> The condition code register ... is mainly intended for use in straight-line code sequences for computing extended-precision integer addition, subtraction, and multiplication.

I don't think your code satisfies the intent, nor do I think the above assumption of truth table for `CC.CF` is valid.

In fact what I think is happening is a truth table like this:

```
CF:  
0    =  (CARRY) or (NO BORROW)
1    =  (NO CARRY) or (BORROW)
```

(the 0 and 1 here are arbitrary; that is also not defined in the manual.)

All examples of code I have tried (about 6 cases, including yours) have fit the definition I have given above.

Having said this, I would think it unwise to depend on this, as it is mostly undocumented.  A safe rule for computer architecture is that undocumented behavior may change in the future.

Answer (score -1):

I think I have found an explanation. There is a note in the PTX manual which says for the sub.cc instruction: "Behavior is the same for unsigned and signed integers."

Comment: I'm not sure why you think this would explain it.  Try this sequence of instructions, and see if your answer explains the result.  Then see if my answer explains the result: `sub.cc.u32 %0, 0, 0;` `addc.cc.u32 %1, 0, 0;`